# nginx suddenly starts to throw permission denied to /var/lib/nginx

Tags: nginx, permissions

I have a nginx server, it works fine about 1 year but two weeks ago server has been moved to another provider. All was ok, but after some time, aapproximatelly 3 days, server start to throw errors on upload files, like:

```
2017/07/26 09:58:18 [crit] 13254#13254: *2829396 open() "/var/lib/nginx/proxy/7/12/0000002127" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 195.82.157.12, server: ***, request: "GET *** HTTP/1.0", upstream: "***", host: "***", referrer: "***"
```

but this is wrong, i even change permissions to 777 for shure, but there was still the same errors.

No other errors was in logs, only "permission denied" with different digital names after /var/lib/nginx/proxy/. 
After restarting nginx all was ok again, but now this errors returns with random interval, about 2 days. The only cure i found is restart.

Can anyone help me or at least give a clue were should I dig to fix this?

Comment: `/var/lib/nginx/proxy` is a default path for temporary files of proxy module on Debian (Ubuntu). You could change it with `proxy_temp_path` directive or find out what's wrong with this path in your in you machine.

Comment: May be you just don't have enough space?

Comment: I too think about space first but no, about 100GB free. Idea to change proxy_tmp_path look intresting, I'll try it, thanks.

Comment: Have you got the solution? What we met is similar with you. Everything goes well after reload but errors throws after random hours or days. I add "client_body_in_file_only    on;" and files save ok, so I think there is no permission error.

Comment: Sorry, nothing to add. We have changed the provider again in couple weeks because of some financial issues and problem dissolved.

Comment: In my case changing temp proxy path with proxy_tmp_path di not solve the problem. I still see the following error: *open() "/nginx_cache_tmp/0000000001" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream* even though /nginx_cache_tmp is owned by the nginx user.

Answer (score 13):

give permissions to `/var/lib/nginx/` using this command :

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/nginx/
```

this worked for me.

Comment: I have to do this repeatedly.

Comment: This fix did not help in my case.

Answer (score 4):

Try this: change nginx `proxy_temp_path` to `/tmp`, edit your proxy config file, add:

```
proxy_temp_path /tmp;
```

and restart nginx.

Answer (score 0):

As for why this *suddenly* started happening for you, I presume it is because NGINX only drops files there when they are greater than 9K. Perhaps you were dealing with smaller or equal sized files previously.

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to be because of the permission issues.

Can you just check what user is nginx running with? And also see what permissions exist on the folder `/var/lib/nginx/proxy/`?

It might be happening that nginx is trying to create a new file with this random name in the proxy folder. But due to incorrect permissions on the base folder, it is unable to create it.

I would suggest giving a chown -R and 777 -R to the `/var/lib/nginx/proxy/` folder itself for the nginx user.

If that does not work, you can also try doing the same on the `/var/lib/nginx/` and see if that works. But, I am not sure how much of a security issue will it lead to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I have. Also, as mentioned by Alexey, it could also be a memory issue as well.

Comment: Ok, if this not clear enough in question, check permission is first thing that I do. All was ok and just for shure i do chmod 777 /var/lib/nginx/

Answer (score -1):

I found a working solution. In my case it was SELinux enforcing rules and permissions, so even I had the correct permissions on temp proxy path like:

```
# ls -l / | grep nginx
drwxrwxrwx.   2 nginx nginx 4096 01-18 11:44 nginx_cache
drwxr-xr-x.   2 nginx nginx    6 01-18 11:44 nginx_cache_tmp
```

nginx user couldn't create any files there.

FIX: disable SELinux

```
# setenforce 0
# sed -i 's/SELINUX=enforcing/SELINUX=permissive/' /etc/selinux/config
```

or a better fix is to configure appropriate permissions for the nginx user.
In this case you may take a look at https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-plus-with-selinux/